# Is there a way to compare the state of an object before and after certain callbacks?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When a comment on our site gets destroyed, the `after_destroy` callback is used to update stats:

```
after_destroy do |p|
  p.topic.update_attribute(:replies, p.replies - 1)
end
```

I want to be able to do the same thing when a comment gets "soft-deleted". When a comment is soft-deleted, the `comment.visible` field is set from `1` to `0`.

Is there a way to tell when this happens during the update callbacks? Something like:

```
after_update do |p|
  if p.visible was changed from 1 to 0, then update stats.
    p.visible.update_attribute(:replies, p.replies - 1)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do `p.visible_changed?` to see if it changed.  You can also see what it changed from and what it changed to with other methods that [`ActiveModel::Dirty`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html) gives you, which is available by default on all `ActiveRecords`.